# "PHP has encountered an Access Violation at 16B357F9"

Tags: php, iis

I'm getting the following error when I visit a specific page of my website. It stopped to work suddenly, without changing any code. THe php code is the original Drupal installation code.

> PHP has encountered an Access
>   Violation at 16B357F9

I'm using Drupal on IIS Server 6. All the rest of the website works.
It might be a server issue ?
Thanks

**Updated**, this is the page: http://lancelmaat.nl/drupal/index.php?q=content/stalkshow

Comment: The question is very vague. It could be anything. Provide a stack trace. See http://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace-win32.php

Comment: I've updated my question with the link... I'm not doing anything.. just visiting. It suddenly stopped to work.

Comment: @Patrick You'll still need to provide more information. Minimum, try to isolate the line of the script that causes that behavior.

Comment: I have no idea what's the line, because it was working perfecty until few seconds ago, and I developed it few days ago. It is drupal cms.. if this helps. Let me check logs, if I find something interesting, I will post again.

Comment: I don't have access to server log files.. tell me what I can do to give you more information. I haven't change any single php line of that page. It is original Drupal code.

Comment: The point is that it was working before, without changing any php code, it stopped to work. Argh, dunno what to do, it is urgent :(

Comment: It could be anything (including hardware issues ie. memory starting to fail), but since it's Windows : you could try restarting IIS or rebooting the server, it might help for a while (especially if the error is due to a memory leak). You could also try running a copy of the site on another machine and see if the error occurs there as well.

Comment: well, I'm running the copy on my localhost and it never had any issue. (Apache). Is there anything I can do if I don't have access to server configuration ? In other words, is it a server error or Drupal error ? (considering I haven't touch php code, and it was working until 1 hour ago).

Comment: all right, not it started to work again (probably server restarted) Second question: Do you think I'm going to have this issue in the future ?

Comment: Argh, down again... very depressing. The PHP memory limit 128M, I don't think this is the issue...

Comment: Saying "it was working before" doesn't really help. Try to a) install the debug tools and get a stack trace – see my first comment and b) step through the code with a debugger and see what is causing it.

Comment: @Artefacto, I have no access to server configuration, I cannot install any debug tool. From the link you passed: "You'll need to install MSVC6". This step is impossible for me.

Comment: OK. Then change the script, write to a file at certain points to see where it fails. But without any debugging tools to assist you... it's going to be difficult to identify the problem.

Comment: OK. I'm making progress. The violation is caused by thumbnails linking to videos.. very strange it is just a row of images with links. Argh.

Comment: sorry for spamming with comment. But I've just realized I get the same error when I add a new project: drupal/index.php?q=node/add/project ... it might be a permissions problem on files folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazing drupal bug with IIS.

I've solved adding ?> at the end of the template page.

Still shocked.

More info: http://drupal.org/node/108106

Comment: @ Patrick I have this problem with IIS & Drupal 7 = 

http://tinyurl.com/6hc33n4

PHP has encountered an Access Violation at 01D9B009

which files so I need to edit by adding ?>

thank you

Comment: @Juc1 I've no idea with Drupal 7 (never used yet). The link in my answer describes the solution for Drupal 6...

Answer (score 0):

If you're running PHP on IIS as ISAPI extension this could produce "PHP has encountered an Access Violation at *Address*". **Try running your application as CGI or FastCGI.**